# How to save state of ubuntu installation in vmware

Tags: ubuntu, snapshot

I want to save the state of ubuntu 13.10 in vmware virutal machine, so I can rollback to previous state if any further configuration i ubuntu goes wrong?

Comment: What version of VMware? What is your host system? Since you tagged this with "snapshot", have you already tried to create a snapshot…?

Answer (score 11):

The other answers here seem to assume the use of VMware Workstation, but since the OP has not yet clarified I will assume VMware Player. VMware Player does not have a snapshot feature, the idea being to entice you to purchase VMware Workstation.

You can get around this by making a copy of your virtual machine using copy & paste, or by creating a .zip backup with free archive tools like 7-zip. To go restore, right click on your virtual machine in VMware Player, choose `Delete from disk`, manually restore your backed up copy from where-ever you saved it, and browse in VMware Player to add it to your virtual machine library. You can also use this to duplicate virtual machines, but this can lead to networking issues unless you refresh the mac address in the virtual machines settings.

Comment: This answer might be more useful if you described _how_ to "make a copy of your virtual machine", etc., since the question asks "How" to do that.

Answer (score 1):

> "File" -> "Virtual Media Manager" -> Choose the hard disk and right
>   click -> "Modify" -> Choose medium type -> "Inmutable"

If you have any question regarding this process, look in the web for: "VirtualBox Immutable Image with a Differencing Disk"

---

> OP is asking for VMware related situation

Yes, I did not realise xD

For **VMware** use the option "Nonpersistent" in VM -> settings -> Hardware -> Nonpersistent

You can find more information following this link:
https://www.vmware.com/support/ws3/doc/ws32_disks2.html

Comment: OP is asking for VMware related situation

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of VMWare (assuming you are using workstation)

https://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_preserve_sshot_taking.html

> 1. Choose VM > Snapshot > Take Snapshot
> 2. Type a name for your snapshot.
>
> Every snapshot must have a unique name. If you type the name of an
>   existing snapshot, a warning appears and you must enter a different
>   name.
>
> 3. If you wish, you may type a description for your snapshot.
>
> Descriptions are useful to identify differences between
>   similarly-named snapshots. Descriptions appear in the snapshot
>   manager.
>
> 4. Click OK.